# jQuery-Trying to emulate a simple Facebook info and feed page through Facebook Graph API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im trying to emulate a simple page which includes facebook info like username, email etc. I'm not able to obtain the user's posts from the json received. Tried various methods like making the feed a different function but all failed. Please help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var fbtoken = 'your token here';

  function getInfo() {

    $.ajax('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' + fbtoken, {

        success: function(response) {
          console.log(response);
          console.log(typeof(response));
          $("#Id").html('<a target="blank" href="https://facebook.com/' + response.id + '">https://facebook.com/' + response.id + '</a>');
          $('#name').text(response.name);
          $('#about').text(response.about);
          $('#birthday').text(response.birthday);
          $("#email").text(response.email);




        }

      }

    );
  }

  function getFeed() {

    $.ajax('https://graph.facebook.com/me/posts?access_token=' + fbtoken, {

      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(typeof(response));
        $("#feed").text(response.posts.data);
      }
    });
  }


  $("#loaddata").on('click', getInfo)
  $("#loadfeed").on('click', getFeed)
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="FacebookPro.js"></script>
  <title>Facebook Mockup</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 align="center">My Facebook Mockup</h1>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 50%" id="loaddata">Run</a>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <h3>Id</h3><span id="Id"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <h3>Name</h3><span id="name"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <h3>About</h3><span id="about"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <h3>Birthday</h3><span id="birthday"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <h3>Email</h3><span id="email"></span>
        </div>




      </div>
      <h2 align="center">Feed</h2>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 50%" id="loadfeed">Run</a>
      <div class="row">
        <h3>FB Feed=</h3><span id="feed"></span>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

</html>
```

You can insert your token in the fbToken variable using [Graph API Explorer in Tools And Support.](https://developers.facebook.com/tools-and-support/)
I think i'm making a mistake in retrieving the data part as it is an object-of-array but i'm having a hard time figuring out how to do it right.

Comment: What are you getting in your console for the response object?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined. I've also updated some code and made the posts a different function as it is not accessed through "...me?" but "...me/posts".

Comment: OK. I've done it finally. Thanks for making me look into my response object of feed. Dont know why i avoided that.